# Need to create JasperReport for generate PDF with PageWidth 15600

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have around 110 columns. Need to generate pdf using JasperReports. Any pageWidth Limitation for generating pdf?

Initially I have given `pageWidth=4600` ,with this width i can able to see 30 columns & values after generating PDF report:

```
<jasperReport ...
pageWidth="4600" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555"
leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" ...>
```

I have to provide `pagewidth=15600`. But if I provide that much page width blank page is generating. How to achieve this?

In this way am creating field:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true"  isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="15600" y="0" width="150" height="25" > <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/><property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/></reportElement>
            <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{loanCycleNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Comment: Sure thank you for your support

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190741/how-to-generate-pdf-reports-that-spans-multiple-pages-horizontally)?